# C# Graphics.DrawImage() throws out of memory exception when trying to combine multiple images

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to combine multiple images to a single one. this is my code right now:

```
    public static Bitmap Merge(List<Image> imgs)
    {
        int outputImageWidth = 0;
        int outputImageHeight = 0;

        foreach (var img in imgs)
        {
            if(outputImageWidth < img.Width)
            {
                outputImageWidth = img.Width;
            }
            outputImageHeight += img.Height;
        }

        outputImageHeight += 1;

        using (Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage);
                graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(new Point(0, outputImage.Height + 1), img.Size), new Rectangle(new Point(), img.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                graphics.Dispose();
                graphics = null;
                img.Dispose();
            }
            foreach (var img in imgs)
            {
                img.Dispose();
            }
            GC.Collect();

            return (Bitmap)outputImage.Clone();
        }
    }
```

While debugging, i figgured out, then whenever I call `graphics.DrawImage(...)` about 100-300mb of memory were allocated. I expected it to get liberated whenever i dispose the object, but with every iteration, the process allocates more memory, until I get an out of memory exceptio (approximately after 30 pages on a 32 Bit process).
Any ideas?

Comment: Your use of `Dispose` seems a little strange to me (double disposes in loop). I don't think a problem but strange. Also, why do you clone the output image and then dispose it? Why not just return it without cloning (that would avoid some memory pressure).

Comment: You should create the graphics object (and put it in a `using(...)`) outside the loop, and reuse it.

Comment: Please tell us how many images there are and what width/height the result would have! - Btw: The source images come in a List, so they have been allocated already and most likely are not the problem. Creating a hug Bitmap often is a wasting/leaking GDI resources..

Comment: @TaW unless I misread the algorithm, it's stacking N images vertically (sum of their height) and width is max of all images width.

Comment: Sure but the actual numbers (hxw) are of the essence. - My last comment ended with a typo. Here is what I meant: _..not the problem. Creating a huge Bitmap often is, or wasting/leaking GDI resources.._

Comment: @Kit Yes you are right, I just tried to Dispose and GC.Collect wherever I could immagine it could help.

Comment: @TaW That could be the problem, the Height of the new Bitmap would be arround 121000 pixel. Is there a way to prevent a "leaking" GDI resource?

Comment: 121000 is really a lot, probably too much. It has to be created as contigous memory. GDI resources are not your problem as each bitmap will only use up one so you have list.count +1 plus a few extras. One workaround may be to create 2 or 3 smaller images and find a way to stitch them together without GDI; maybe a lib will help. Search for Bitmap size limits in winforms and GDI+  !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
public static Bitmap Merge(List<Image> imgs)
{
    ...

    var outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb));
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
    {
        foreach (var img in imgs)
        {
            using (img)
                graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(new Point(0, outputImage.Height + 1), img.Size), new Rectangle(new Point(), img.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);                 
        }

        return outputImage;
    }
}
```

This

- features `using` blocks that allow for `Dispose` to always be called, even if there are exceptions thrown part of the way through
- uses a single `Graphics` throughout the process
- doesn't allocate the (huge) bitmap twice

You will, of course, have to dispose of the resulting bitmap outside of this method once you're done with it.

Comment: I tried your solution, now the image seems to be created successfully, but i had to save it as file, because of the using, after returning the image it was Disposed. Now on the outputimage.Save(path); I get "Generic error in GDI+"